# Is there any other substance which doesn't have mass such as light?

Tags: visible-light, field-theory

folks!
I know that "Light" is a wonderful substance which **doesn't have mass**. Such a cool theory but still come on no one got this question? Is there any other substance which doesn't have mass such as light?

Comment: Photons rest mass is zero but when they travel at ultimate speed they do carry energy that means they must have some mass* according to E=mc²

Comment: @KrishnaDeshpandeKD That is false. $E=mc^2$ only holds in the rest frame of the particle and the photon does not have a rest frame. The energy of a particle with some momentum $p$ (such as a photon) is given by $E^2 = m^2c^4 +p^2 c^2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the [Standard Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model), which describes the fundamental particles out of which everything is made, the massless particles are the photon and the gluon. The photon is the particle associated to the electromagnetic interaction (so light) and the gluon is associated to the strong interaction, which hold the proton and the neutron together. Neutrinos were thought to be massless too, but it turned out they have a very very small mass (in fact we don't know precisely what their masses are, just their differences and the fact that they must be very small).

The graviton, the hypothetical particle associated with gravity, is also massless. I say hypothetical because it has never been observed (and probably won't be for the foreseeable future), but it would be very weird indeed if it turned out it didn't exist.